# Cannot convert from void to String error

Tags: java, encryption, joptionpane

I'm trying to make a simple program to encrypt and decrypt a message that a user enters. The problem is that in console everything works fine, but when I try to use JOptionPane I get an error stating that I cannot convert from void to string. The encrypt method works fine with JOptionPane. Its the decrypt method that has the problem. Below is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Encrypt {

    public static final int ALPHASIZE = 26;
    public static final char[] alpha = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G',
            'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
            'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

    protected char[] encrypt = new char[ALPHASIZE];
    protected char[] decrypt = new char[ALPHASIZE];

    public Encrypt() {
        for (int i = 0; i < ALPHASIZE; i++)
            encrypt[i] = alpha[(i + 3) % ALPHASIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < ALPHASIZE; i++)
            decrypt[encrypt[i] - 'A'] = alpha[i];
    }

    public String encryptMessage(String secret) {
        char[] mess = secret.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < mess.length; i++)
            if (Character.isUpperCase(mess[i]))
                mess[i] = encrypt[mess[i] - 'A'];

        return new String(mess);

    }

    public String decryptMessage(String secret) {
        char[] mess = secret.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < mess.length; i++)
            if (Character.isUpperCase(mess[i]))
                mess[i] = decrypt[mess[i] - 'A'];

        return new String(mess);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Encrypt e = new Encrypt();

        // String secret = "THIS IS THE SECRET MESSAGE";
        // secret = e.encryptMessage(secret);
        // System.out.println("Encrypted: " + secret);
        // secret = e.decryptMessage(secret);
        // System.out.println("Decrypted: " + secret);

        String secret = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter message to be encrypted");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.encryptMessage(secret));

        // this is where the problem is
        String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Do you want to convert the message? (Y/N)");
        if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
            secret = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.decryptMessage(secret)));
    }
}
```

Comment: showMessageDialog() does not return a string. The return type is void.

Answer (score 1):

You are using one of the 3 [overloaded](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29) [`showMessageDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon%29), which all return `void`, i.e. nothing.  It looks like you only want to display the decrypted message, so you aren't expecting anything to be returned.  Just as in your console attempt, you aren't assigning the result of `System.out.println` to anything, so you shouldn't do the same with `JOptionPane`.

Remove the assignment.  Change

```
secret = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.decryptMessage(secret)));
```

to

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.decryptMessage(secret));
```

Comment: I believe he also has an extra closing parenthesis at the end of that line.

Comment: @gla3dr Good catch; I've removed the extra `)`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to rgettman's answer, if you *do* want to store the value in `secret`, I would suggest this:

```
secret = e.decryptMessage(secret);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, secret);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it your way and it works perfect.